# How to predict test score just using gender and age and weight by PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

how to predict test score(int)?
Only age, weight, gender by using PyTorch?

training data is like below

```
age, weight, gender, test score
20, 80, "male", 80
25, 90, "male", 10
```

PyTorch tutorial shows me sample code of image classification, but I need just predict test score (int).

How to get Int form Int in pytorch?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make 101 classes (0, ..., 100) to be predicted with your classifier.